# Java IDE says { expected on the first line starting with public class (program name) despite me already having it

Tags: java, curly-braces

Here's my code:

```
public class methodAssignment {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyboardReader reader= new KeyboardReader();
        int num1=reader.readInt("Enter the length of the rectangle: ");
        int num2=reader.readInt("Enter the width of the rectangle: ");
        
        int perimeter=rectPerimeter(num1, num2);
        
        System.out.print("\nThe perimeter of the rectangle is "+perimeter+".");
    }

    public static int rectPerimeter(int length, int width)
    {
        return 2*length+2*width;
    }
}
```

I've tried adding another { to the end of the line, but that just causes more errors as you'd expect. What am I missing?

Comment: 1) There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the braces in the code you've shown us.  2) Q: Did you show us your *COMPLETE* code???  3) Q: What about "KeyboardReader"?

Comment: @paulsm4 2) Believe me, this is the whole thing, and I have no other errors.

Comment: I believe you - it's just perplexing.  Please update your question: 1) copy/paste the exact error message, 2) specify what Java compiler and/or IDE you're using, and 3) tell us about "KeyboardReader". The fact that your code references it - without any corresponding "import" stateument, is the *ONLY* thing I see in your entire code snippet that could possibly cause a compile error.

Comment: Another suggestion: you could do worse than starting from scratch: typing just your classname (I'd use [CamelCase](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions) `MethodAssignment`) and an empty `static void main (String[] args) {}` into a new, clean file and see if that compiles. Please do let us know what happens

Answer (score -1):

You are missing absolutely nothing. That code you pasted in this question? Toss it in a text file, call that file `methodAssignment.java`, and tell javac to compile it, and it'll work fine. You're evidently either not compiling the file you pasted but some other file with syntax errors, or you aren't invoking `javac`, but invoking `shmavac`, the java-esque bad sheep of the family. Go for the real deal :)

Comment: I agree: the OP is "missing absolutely nothing".  But ... 1) I've never heard of "shmavac", and 2) my compile fails with "error: cannot find symbol KeyboardReader".  Q: What's shmavac?  Q: Did your "methodAssignment.java" actually compile without any errors?

Comment: shmavac is a jokey way to say: Your javac is corrupted. The error OP is getting is clearly not 'KeyboardReader isn't there'. It's rather obvious that this isn't OP's problem; they have KeyboardReader.java/KeyboardReader.class in the right place. It actually compiled without errors once I created a dummy KeyboardReader. Why are you aggressively questioning this answer?

Comment: Nothing is "obvious" until clearly stated one way or the other.  As an aside - that's precisely the main reason I tend to avoid Lombok like the plague.  I prefer the code to always explicitly state what's happening - I hate "implicit magic" :(

Comment: @paulsm4 Java is not a good language if you hate implicit magic. The sheer amount of implicit magic the VM is doing to your code as it hotspots is orders of magnitude beyond what javac does, which is already impressive (lombok is minor leagues in comparison).